# Magento home page categories editing

Tags: magento

i want to add "add to cart having  quantity option" in all my products in home page of my magento website in product categories like best selling products,new books,etc all those displaying in my homepage.How i can do this??

Comment: What do you mean with "... having quantity option"?

Comment: quanity means users should able to select no fo items to buy

Comment: i want my magento home page web site look like http://bigbasket.com/..

Answer (score 0):

To add a product to cart from anywhere we should have the url to redirect like `www.domain.com/checkout/cart/add/product/121/qty/3` where 123 is product ID and 3 is qty.

So all you need to do that get qty and product id onclick button  and append in url. But the code depends on your home page html.

I'm providing example that how we can do same from category page

edit {theme}/catalog/product/list.phtml

provide a input box qty just before the add to cart button

```
Qty:<input type="text" class="qty" value="1" product_id="<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" />
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" path = "<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product).'qty/1' ?>" onclick="_addToCart(this.previousElementSibling)"  ><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
```

and just add a js method at the end of the file

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function _addToCart(v1){
    var cartPath = "<?php  echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart/add/') ?>";
    cartPath = cartPath + "product/" + v1.getAttribute('product_id') + "/qty/" + v1.value;
    setLocation(cartPath);
}
</script>
```

Comment: brother i have done already this it affected category pages not homepage.

Comment: this was the example for category page. Only You know how you have programmed your home page. you have to adjust your code as per this example and implement in home page.

Comment: can you tell me normally where is the code writen for homepage in magento.i am unable to get it

Comment: http://themeforest.net/item/gala-electronues-market-responsive-theme/full_screen_preview/4138219--------this is the website template i am using but my client wants add to cart option in homepage where and what to edit

Comment: your theme might be using file {theme}/template/catalog/product/new.phtml to display new products at home page. find out where is your button defined for "add to cart" and replace that code with above code OR if you dont have add to cart button then place above somewhere before wishlist link and then place js at the end of page in script tag. it will work. The target should clear to you that finally we wnat a url similar to `www.domain.com/index.php/checkout/cart/add/product/121/qty/3` to be triggered on click of button